# Tagged Value and pattern value changes to true after transforming a package

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect, and when I want to transform a package from the logical Layer to the physical, using a transformation template, the Tagged values changes as below:
[image]

What should I modify in the transformation template to have the same values in the output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard DDL MDA transform does not directly support Tagged Values, so in the Transformation Template, I added some Tagged Value substitution Macros Like:

```
%if attTag:"length" != ""%
      Tag
      {
       name = "length"
       value=%qt%%attTag:"length"%%qt%
       }
    %endIf%
    %if attTag:"minLength" != ""%
       Tag
      {
       name = "minLength"
       value=%qt%%attTag:"minLength"%%qt%
       }
    %endIf%
    %if attTag:"maxLength" != ""%
       Tag
      {
       name = "maxLength"
       value=%qt%%attTag:"maxLength"%%qt%
       }
    %endIf%
```